# BibTeX You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry XXXXXX

Tags: bibtex

I have an error in my latex project (overleaf). It was working fine but something happend and the following error appeared:

> BibTeX You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry zhang2020birds
> .. myplain.bst, line 1143

I didn't change anything in my project. I don't know why it appears.

I'm getting this error for each reference I have in my project.

This is the content of `myplan.bst` file, and row 1143 is the 8th row from down to up which is :`ITERATE {call.type$}`.

```
% BibTeX standard bibliography style `plain'
   % Version 0.99b (8-Dec-10 release) for BibTeX versions 0.99a or later.
   % Copyright (C) 1984, 1985, 1988, 2010 Howard Trickey and Oren Patashnik.
   % Unlimited copying and redistribution of this file are permitted as long as
   % it is unmodified.  Modifications (and redistribution of modified versions)
   % are also permitted, but only if the resulting file is renamed to something
   % besides btxbst.doc, plain.bst, unsrt.bst, alpha.bst, and abbrv.bst.
   % This restriction helps ensure that all standard styles are identical.
   % The file btxbst.doc has the documentation for this style.

ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    edition
    editor
    howpublished
    institution
    journal
    key
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    volume
    yearpublished
    location
    year
    month
    day
  }
  {}
  { label }

INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }

FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
}

STRINGS { s t }

FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}

FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}

FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
    'skip$
    { output.state before.all =
        'skip$
        { after.sentence 'output.state := }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}

FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\em " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}

INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        { namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            { numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                { " et~al." * }
                { " and " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor empty$
    { "" }
    { editor format.names
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title "t" change.case$ }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{ 't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
        { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
            { "--" *
              t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
            }
            {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
                { "-" *
                  t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
                }
              while$
            }
          if$
        }
        { t #1 #1 substring$ *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
      if$
    }
  while$
}




FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year empty$
    { month empty$
        { "" }
            { day empty$
                { "" }
                { "there's a day but no year and month in " cite$ warning$ day
                }
              if$
            }
        { "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$
          month
        }
      if$
    }
    { month empty$
        { day empty$
            { month " " * year * }
            { "there's a day but no month in " cite$ warning$ day
            }
          if$
        }
        { day " " * month * " " * year * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title emphasize
}

FUNCTION {tie.or.space.connect}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
    { "~" }
    { " " }
  if$
  swap$ * *
}

FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
    'pop$
    { "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { "volume" volume tie.or.space.connect
      series empty$
        'skip$
        { " of " * series emphasize *}
      if$
      "volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
        { series field.or.null }
        { output.state mid.sentence =
            { "number" }
            { "Number" }
          if$
          number tie.or.space.connect
          series empty$
            { "there's a number but no series in " cite$ * warning$ }
            { " in " * series * " " * year *}
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.year.series}
{ series empty$
    {""}
    { year empty$
        { "" }
        { " (" * series * " " * year * ")" * }
        if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.location}
{ location empty$
    { "" }
    {location}
    if$
}

FUNCTION {format.year}
{ year empty$
    { "" }
    { " (" * year * ")" *}
    if$
}



FUNCTION {format.month}
{ month empty$
    { "" }
    {month}
        
   if$
}

FUNCTION {format.day}
{ day empty$
    { "" }
    {day}
        
   if$
}

FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition empty$
    { "" }
    { output.state mid.sentence =
        { edition "l" change.case$ " edition" * }
        { edition "t" change.case$ " edition" * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

INTEGERS { multiresult }

FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
  #0 'multiresult :=
    { multiresult not
      t empty$ not
      and
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "-" =
      swap$ duplicate$ "," =
      swap$ "+" =
      or or
        { #1 'multiresult := }
        { t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
      if$
    }
  while$
  multiresult
}

FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages empty$
    { "" }
    { pages multi.page.check
        { "pp." pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }
        { "p." pages tie.or.space.connect }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  number empty$
    'skip$
    { "(" number * ")" * *
      volume empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ format.pages }
        { ":" * pages n.dashify * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
    'format.pages
    { type empty$
        { "chapter" }
        { type "l" change.case$ }
      if$
      chapter tie.or.space.connect
      pages empty$
        'skip$
        { ", " * format.pages * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ booktitle empty$
    { "" }
    { editor empty$
        { "In: " booktitle emphasize * }
        { "In: " format.editors * ", " * booktitle emphasize * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {empty.misc.check}
{ author empty$ title empty$ howpublished empty$
  month empty$ year empty$ note empty$
  and and and and and
  key empty$ not and
    { "all relevant fields are empty in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ type empty$
    'skip$
    { pop$
      type "t" change.case$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ type empty$
    { "Technical Report" }
    'type
  if$
  number empty$
    { "t" change.case$ }
    { number tie.or.space.connect }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{ key empty$
    { journal empty$
        { "need key or journal for " cite$ * " to crossref " * crossref *
          warning$
          ""
        }
        { "In {\em " journal * "\/}" * }
      if$
    }
    { "In: " key * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.crossref.editor}
{ editor #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  editor num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$ " et~al." * }
    { #2 <
        'skip$
        { editor #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
            { " et~al." * }
            { " and " * editor #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume empty$
    { "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref of " * crossref * warning$
      "In: "
    }
    { "Volume" volume tie.or.space.connect
      " of " *
    }
  if$
  editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
        { series empty$
            { "need editor, key, or series for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
              crossref * warning$
              "" *
            }
            { "{\em " * series * "\/}" * }
          if$
        }
        { key * }
      if$
    }
    { format.crossref.editor * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{ editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
        { booktitle empty$
            { "need editor, key, or booktitle for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
              crossref * warning$
              ""
            }
            { "In {\em " booktitle * "\/}" * }
          if$
        }
        { "In: " key * }
      if$
    }
    { "In: " format.crossref.editor * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.year output
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.year output
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
    }
    { new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {booklet}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  howpublished address new.block.checkb
  howpublished output
  address output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
    }
    { format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.chapter.pages output
      new.sentence
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
      format.edition output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.year output
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
  {format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
   format.bvolume output
   format.date output
   format.location output
   new.sentence
   format.year.series output
   format.pages output
   new.block
   address empty$
    {
    organization    publisher new.sentence.checkb
    organization output
    publisher output
    }
    { organization output
      publisher output
    address
      output.nonnull
      }
      if$
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
    format.pages output
    }
  if$
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {conference} { inproceedings }

FUNCTION {manual}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { organization empty$
        'skip$
        { organization output.nonnull
          address output
        }
      if$
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  author empty$
    { organization empty$
        { address new.block.checka
          address output
        }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
    { organization address new.block.checkb
      organization output
      address output
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  "Master's thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  title howpublished new.block.checkb
  format.title output
  howpublished new.block.checka
  howpublished output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
  empty.misc.check
}

FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  "PhD thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {proceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  editor empty$
    { organization output }
    { format.editors output.nonnull }
  if$
  format.year output
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  format.bvolume output
  format.date output
  format.location output
  format.year.series output
 format.pages output
  address empty$
    { editor empty$
        { publisher new.sentence.checka }
        { organization publisher new.sentence.checkb
          organization output
        }
      if$
      publisher output
    }
    { address output.nonnull
      new.sentence
      editor empty$
        'skip$
        { organization output }
      if$
      publisher output
    }
  if$
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {techreport}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  format.tr.number output.nonnull
  institution "institution" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {unpublished}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  note "note" output.check
  format.date output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }

MACRO {jan} {"January"}

MACRO {feb} {"February"}

MACRO {mar} {"March"}

MACRO {apr} {"April"}

MACRO {may} {"May"}

MACRO {jun} {"June"}

MACRO {jul} {"July"}

MACRO {aug} {"August"}

MACRO {sep} {"September"}

MACRO {oct} {"October"}

MACRO {nov} {"November"}

MACRO {dec} {"December"}

MACRO {acmcs} {"ACM Computing Surveys"}

MACRO {acta} {"Acta Informatica"}

MACRO {cacm} {"Communications of the ACM"}

MACRO {ibmjrd} {"IBM Journal of Research and Development"}

MACRO {ibmsj} {"IBM Systems Journal"}

MACRO {ieeese} {"IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering"}

MACRO {ieeetc} {"IEEE Transactions on Computers"}

MACRO {ieeetcad}
 {"IEEE Transactions on Computer-Aided Design of Integrated Circuits"}

MACRO {ipl} {"Information Processing Letters"}

MACRO {jacm} {"Journal of the ACM"}

MACRO {jcss} {"Journal of Computer and System Sciences"}

MACRO {scp} {"Science of Computer Programming"}

MACRO {sicomp} {"SIAM Journal on Computing"}

MACRO {tocs} {"ACM Transactions on Computer Systems"}

MACRO {tods} {"ACM Transactions on Database Systems"}

MACRO {tog} {"ACM Transactions on Graphics"}

MACRO {toms} {"ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software"}

MACRO {toois} {"ACM Transactions on Office Information Systems"}

MACRO {toplas} {"ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems"}

MACRO {tcs} {"Theoretical Computer Science"}

READ

FUNCTION {sortify}
{ purify$
  "l" change.case$
}

INTEGERS { len }

FUNCTION {chop.word}
{ 's :=
  'len :=
  s #1 len substring$ =
    { s len #1 + global.max$ substring$ }
    's
  if$
}

FUNCTION {sort.format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  ""
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { nameptr #1 >
        { "   " * }
        'skip$
      if$
      s nameptr "{vv{ } }{ll{ }}{  ff{ }}{  jj{ }}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr numnames = t "others" = and
        { "et al" * }
        { t sortify * }
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {sort.format.title}
{ 't :=
  "A " #2
    "An " #3
      "The " #4 t chop.word
    chop.word
  chop.word
  sortify
  #1 global.max$ substring$
}

FUNCTION {author.sort}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need author or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.sort}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { "to sort, need author, editor, or key in " cite$ * warning$
              ""
            }
            { key sortify }
          if$
        }
        { editor sort.format.names }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.organization.sort}
{ author empty$
    { organization empty$
        { key empty$
            { "to sort, need author, organization, or key in " cite$ * warning$
              ""
            }
            { key sortify }
          if$
        }
        { "The " #4 organization chop.word sortify }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.organization.sort}
{ editor empty$
    { organization empty$
        { key empty$
            { "to sort, need editor, organization, or key in " cite$ * warning$
              ""
            }
            { key sortify }
          if$
        }
        { "The " #4 organization chop.word sortify }
      if$
    }
    { editor sort.format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {presort}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.sort
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.organization.sort
        { type$ "manual" =
            'author.organization.sort
            'author.sort
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
  "    "
  *
  year field.or.null sortify
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}

ITERATE {presort}

SORT

STRINGS { longest.label }

INTEGERS { number.label longest.label.width }

FUNCTION {initialize.longest.label}
{ "" 'longest.label :=
  #1 'number.label :=
  #0 'longest.label.width :=
}

FUNCTION {longest.label.pass}
{ number.label int.to.str$ 'label :=
  number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
  label width$ longest.label.width >
    { label 'longest.label :=
      label width$ 'longest.label.width :=
    }
    'skip$
  if$
}

EXECUTE {initialize.longest.label}

ITERATE {longest.label.pass}

FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{"  longest.label  * "}" * write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {begin.bib}

EXECUTE {init.state.consts}

ITERATE {call.type$}

FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {end.bib}
```

## Edit

The project consists of three main files, `main.tex`, `myplain.bst`, and references.bib, and this is the content of `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linktoc=all,    
    linkcolor=blue, 
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\newcommand{\bc}{\cellcolor{lightgray}}
\newcommand{\bg}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\makeatletter
\let\old@endpart\@endpart
\renewcommand\@endpart[1][]{%
\begin{quote}#1\end{quote}%
\old@endpart}
\makeatother


\def\rot{\rotatebox}
\hypersetup{linktocpage}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\number\numexpr\value{section}\relax}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\number\numexpr\value{subsection}\relax}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\number\numexpr\value{subsubsection}\relax}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}




\begin{document}
\setcode{utf8}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

% \clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagebreak
\pagenumbering{arabic}



\chapter{Introduction}
\bg{ news \cite{zhang2020birds} perspective.}



\bibliographystyle{myplain}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

and this is the content of `references.bib`:

```
@article{zhang2020birds,
  title={Birds of a Feather Flock Together: Satirical News Detection via Language Model Differentiation},
  author={Zhang, Yigeng and Yang, Fan and Zhang, Yifan and Dragut, Eduard and Mukherjee, Arjun},
  journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:2007.02164},
  year={2020}
}
```

Comment: You have a slightly better chance of getting a good answer if in addition to your `.bst` file you share an example `.bib` entry and a short document citing that bib entry that reproduces the error message you are asking about.

Comment: @moewe , I added the full project. you can just create a new project in overleaf and copy the content of what I added.

Comment: @Ghanem could you please provide the changes needed to fix the problem? I am using a template from the International Journal of Software Engineering and Knowledge Engineering and I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems in `myplain.bst` mostly in relation to the date and series field. Please report this as a bug to the maintainer/developer of your template. If there is no one maintaining the template you should seriously consider not using the template and/or protesting if you are required to use it. It is unreasonable to require people to use an unsupported and broken template.

The main problem is that in

```
day " " * month * " " * year *
```

in `format.date` there is no check if `day` actually exists. At that point we have checked for `month` and `year`, but not for `day`. I added a test.

There are also some other problems with string concatenation that aren't uniform across branches in tests.

The other changes are to make the warnings work properly.

```
--- myplain-orig.bst    2020-07-14 19:03:34.384191800 +0200
+++ myplain.bst 2020-07-14 19:42:29.166464000 +0200
@@ -267,13 +267,13 @@
 FUNCTION {format.date}
 { year empty$
     { month empty$
-        { "" }
-            { day empty$
-                { "" }
-                { "there's a day but no year and month in " cite$ warning$ day
-                }
-              if$
+        { day empty$
+            { "" }
+            { "there's a day but no year and month in " cite$ * warning$
+              day
             }
+          if$
+        }
         { "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$
           month
         }
@@ -281,12 +281,17 @@
     }
     { month empty$
         { day empty$
-            { month " " * year * }
-            { "there's a day but no month in " cite$ warning$ day
+            { year }
+            { "there's a day but no month in " cite$ * warning$
+              day " " * year *
             }
           if$
         }
-        { day " " * month * " " * year * }
+        { day empty$
+            { "" }
+            { day " " * }
+          if$
+          month * " " * year * }
       if$
     }
   if$
@@ -349,8 +354,8 @@
     {""}
     { year empty$
         { "" }
-        { " (" * series * " " * year * ")" * }
-        if$
+        { " (" series * " " * year * ")" * }
+      if$
     }
   if$
 }
@@ -365,25 +370,21 @@
 FUNCTION {format.year}
 { year empty$
     { "" }
-    { " (" * year * ")" *}
-    if$
+    { " (" year * ")" *}
+  if$
 }
 
-
-
 FUNCTION {format.month}
 { month empty$
     { "" }
-    {month}
-        
+    { month }
    if$
 }
 
 FUNCTION {format.day}
 { day empty$
     { "" }
-    {day}
-        
+    { day }
    if$
 }
```

Comment: but this is a template from the university and I didn't change anything in it! weird!, anyways, sorry it's not clear for me what you changed .. Thanks, it's clear now!

Comment: @Ghanem This is the output of the `diff` utility. The lines starting with `@@` show the line number in the original file. Lines starting with `-` were removed, lines starting with `+` were added. So the first change would be to replace `{ "there's a day but no year and month in " cite$ warning$ day` with `{ "there's a day but no year and month in " cite$ * warning$ day` etc. etc.

Comment: it's clear now. sorry because of the limit in the length if the post I discarded another references which caused another error regarding the `month` and another same one for day: `BibTeX `month' is a missing field, not a string, for entry yang2017satirical` and here is the reference: `@inproceedings{poddar2018predicting,
  title={{Predicting A Neural Approach}},
  author={Subramayam, Shruti},
  booktitle={Artificial Intelligence},
  pages={65--72},
  year={2018},
  organization={IEEE}
}` , could you please have a look over it?

Comment: plz wait I'll update the post

Comment: @Ghanem Oh, yes the style is even more broken than I at first realised. Try now, please.

Comment: I still get this error: `BibTeX You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry Litschko:2018` and this is the ref.: `@inproceedings{Litschko:2018,
 author = {Ldsasan},
 title = {dasd},
 booktitle = {Tdsadieval},
 series = {dsa},
 year = {3234},
 pages = {1253--1256},
} `

Comment: @Ghanem That should now be fixed, check the edit, please. This style is really quite seriously broken. It looks like people didn't even check the changes they applied (the errors are quite visible)!

Comment: thank you so much .. now it works.