# Latex error 'can't pop an empty literal stack for entry XXX'

Tags: bibtex, pdftex

I'm currently writing my master thesis using the template from my university on Overleaf, which uses BibTex for references. Document class is scrrprt. For some of my references `I get the error You cant pop an empty literal stack for entry XXX`, whereas others work just fine. How can I get rid of this error?

Here is an mwe where I get the error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,headsepline,bibtotoc]{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
bla \cite{abdullah_technological_2023}, \cite{meredith_numerical_2011}, \cite{iskra_convective_2007}, \cite{stull_wet-bulb_2011}

% References
\bibliographystyle{refstyle}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

References where everything works fine are e.g.:

```
@article{iskra_convective_2007,
    title = {Convective mass transfer coefficient for a hydrodynamically developed airflow in a short rectangular duct},
    volume = {50},
    issn = {00179310},
    url = {https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0017931006005990},
    doi = {10.1016/j.ijheatmasstransfer.2006.10.026},
    language = {en},
    number = {11-12},
    urldate = {2023-05-30},
    journal = {International Journal of Heat and Mass Transfer},
    author = {Iskra, Conrad R. and Simonson, Carey J.},
    month = jun,
    year = {2007},
    pages = {2376--2393}
}

@article{stull_wet-bulb_2011,
    title = {Wet-{Bulb} {Temperature} from {Relative} {Humidity} and {Air} {Temperature}},
    volume = {50},
    issn = {1558-8424, 1558-8432},
    url = {https://journals.ametsoc.org/view/journals/apme/50/11/jamc-d-11-0143.1.xml},
    doi = {10.1175/JAMC-D-11-0143.1},
    number = {11},
    urldate = {2023-05-30},
    journal = {Journal of Applied Meteorology and Climatology},
    author = {Stull, Roland},
    month = nov,
    year = {2011},
    pages = {2267--2269}
}
```

For the following references, Overleaf shows the error:

```
@article{abdullah_technological_2023,
    title = {Technological development of evaporative cooling systems and its integration with air dehumidification processes: {A} review},
    volume = {283},
    issn = {03787788},
    shorttitle = {Technological development of evaporative cooling systems and its integration with air dehumidification processes},
    url = {https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S037877882300035X},
    doi = {10.1016/j.enbuild.2023.112805},
    language = {en},
    urldate = {2023-07-18},
    journal = {Energy and Buildings},
    author = {Abdullah, Shekh and Zubir, Mohd Nashrul Bin Mohd and Muhamad, Mohd Ridha Bin and Newaz, Kazi Md Salim and Öztop, Hakan F. and Alam, Md Shadab and Shaikh, Kaleemullah},
    month = mar,
    year = {2023},
    pages = {112805--112832}
}

@article{meredith_numerical_2011,
    title = {A {Numerical} {Model} for {Simulation} of {Thin}-{Film} {Water} {Transport} {Over} {Solid} {Fuel} {Surfaces}},
    volume = {10},
    issn = {18174299},
    url = {http://iafss.haifire.com/wordpress/digitalarchive/view.php?c=1&v=10&p=415},
    doi = {10.3801/IAFFS.FSS.10-415},
    language = {en},
    urldate = {2023-08-14},
    journal = {Fire Safety Science},
    author = {Meredith, K. and Xin, Y. and de Vries, J.},
    year = {2011},
    pages = {415--428}
}
```

The bst-file used for the bibliography style is the following:

```
ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    edition
    editor
    howpublished
    institution
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    volume
    year
  }
  {}
  { label }

INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block before.title}

FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
  #4 'before.title :=
}

STRINGS { s t }

FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
    { add.period$ write$
      newline$
      "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            % next if is for use with `new' FUNCTION {after.authors}
            { output.state before.title =
                { ": " * write$ }
                { add.period$ " " * write$ }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}

FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}

FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
    'skip$
    { output.state before.all =
        'skip$
        { after.sentence 'output.state := }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

% new one -> sets what is specified in FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
% if `before.title 'output.state = ... if$' is true
FUNCTION {after.authors}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { before.title 'output.state := }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}

FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\em " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {scapify}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\sc " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}

INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
    { namesleft #1 >
        { ", " * t * }
        { numnames #2 >
        { " " * }
        'skip$
          if$
          t "others" =
        { " et~al." * }
        { " und " * t * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

STRINGS { last.authors }

FUNCTION {init.last.authors}
{ "" 'last.authors :=
}

FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.names scapify }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.organization}
{ organization empty$
    { "" 'last.authors :=
      ""
    }
    { organization last.authors =
        { "\leavevmode\vrule height 2pt depth -1.6pt width 23pt" }
        { organization scapify }
      if$
      organization 'last.authors :=
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor empty$
    { "" 'last.authors :=
      ""
    }
    { editor last.authors =
        { "\leavevmode\vrule height 2pt depth -1.6pt width 23pt" }
    { editor format.names scapify }
      if$
      editor num.names$ #1 >
        { ", eds." * }
    { ", ed." * }
      if$
      editor 'last.authors :=
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.ineditors}
{ editor empty$
    { "" }
    { editor format.names
      editor num.names$ #1 >
    { ", eds." * }
    { ", ed." * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title emphasize
}

FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{ 't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
    { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
        { "--" *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
        {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
        { "-" *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
          while$
        }
      if$
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ *
      t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
    }
      if$
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year empty$
    { month empty$
    { "" }
    { "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$
      month
    }
      if$
    }
    { month empty$
    'year
    { month " " * year * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title emphasize
}

FUNCTION {tie.or.space.connect}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
    { "~" }
    { " " }
  if$
  swap$ * *
}

FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
    'pop$
    { "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { "Vol.~" volume *
      series empty$
    'skip$
    { " of " * series * }
      if$
      "volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
    { series field.or.null }
    { "no.~" number *
      series empty$
        { "there's a number but no series in " cite$ * warning$ }
        { " in " * series * }
      if$
    }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition empty$
    { "" }
    { edition "l" change.case$ ".~Auflage" * }
  if$
}

INTEGERS { multiresult }

FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
  #0 'multiresult :=
    { multiresult not
      t empty$ not
      and
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "-" =
      swap$ duplicate$ "," =
      swap$ "+" =
      or or
    { #1 'multiresult := }
    { t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
      if$
    }
  while$
  multiresult
}

FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages empty$
    { "" }
    { pages multi.page.check
    { "S.~" pages n.dashify * }
    { "S.~" pages * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.vol.year}
{ volume empty$
    { "empty volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
    { ", Vol.~" * volume * }
  if$
  number empty$
    { "empty number in " cite$ * warning$ }
    { "No.~" number * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
    'format.pages
    { type empty$
    { "ch.~" chapter * }
    { type "l" change.case$ chapter tie.or.space.connect }
      if$
      pages empty$
    'skip$
    { ", " * format.pages * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ booktitle empty$
    { "" }
    { editor empty$
    { "In: " booktitle * }
    { "In: " booktitle * ", " * format.ineditors * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {empty.misc.check}
{ author empty$ title empty$ howpublished empty$
  month empty$ year empty$ note empty$
  and and and and and
  key empty$ not and
    { "all relevant fields are empty in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ type empty$
    'skip$
    { pop$
      type
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ type empty$
    { "Tech. Rep." }
    'type
  if$
  number empty$
    { "l" change.case$ }
    { number tie.or.space.connect }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{ key empty$
    { journal empty$
    { "need key or journal for " cite$ * " to crossref " * crossref *
      warning$
      ""
    }
    { "in " journal * }
      if$
    }
    { "in " key * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.crossref.editor}
{ editor #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  editor num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$ " et~al." * }
    { #2 <
    'skip$
    { editor #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
        { " et~al." * }
        { " and " * editor #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
      if$
    }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume empty$
    { "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref of " * crossref * warning$
      "in "
    }
    { "vol.~" volume *
      " of " *
    }
  if$
  editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
    { series empty$
        { "need editor, key, or series for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
          crossref * warning$
          "" *
        }
        { series * }
      if$
    }
    { key * }
      if$
    }
    { format.crossref.editor * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{ editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
    { booktitle empty$
        { "need editor, key, or booktitle for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
          crossref * warning$
          ""
        }
        { "in " booktitle * }
      if$
    }
    { "in " key * }
      if$
    }
    { "in " format.crossref.editor * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  after.authors
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal "journal" output.check
      format.vol.year output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull }
  if$
  format.pages output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
    { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
    'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  after.authors
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
    }
    { new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull 
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {booklet}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  after.authors
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  howpublished new.block.checka
  howpublished output
  address output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
    { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
    'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  after.authors
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
    }
    { format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull 
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  after.authors
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
      format.edition output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull }
  if$
  format.chapter.pages output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  after.authors
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      address empty$
    { organization output
      publisher output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { address output.nonnull
      format.date "year" output.check
      organization output
      publisher output
    }
      if$
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull }
  if$
  format.pages output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {conference} { inproceedings }

FUNCTION {manual}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.organization output }
    { format.authors output.nonnull }
  if$
  after.authors
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  author empty$
    'skip$
    { organization output }
  if$
  address output
  format.edition output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  after.authors
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  "Master's thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  after.authors
  format.title output
  new.block
  howpublished new.block.checka
  howpublished output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
  empty.misc.check
}

FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  after.authors
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  "PhD thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {proceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  editor empty$
    { format.organization output }
    { format.editors output.nonnull }
  if$
  after.authors
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  format.bvolume output
  format.number.series output
  address empty$
    { editor empty$
    'skip$
    { organization output }
      if$
      publisher output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { address output.nonnull
      format.date "year" output.check
      editor empty$
    'skip$
    { organization output }
      if$
      publisher output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {techreport}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  after.authors
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  format.tr.number output.nonnull
  institution "institution" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {unpublished}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  after.authors
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  note "note" output.check
  format.date output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }

MACRO {jan} {"Januar"}
MACRO {feb} {"Februar"}
MACRO {mar} {"Maerz"}
MACRO {apr} {"April"}
MACRO {may} {"Mai"}
MACRO {jun} {"Juni"}
MACRO {jul} {"Juli"}
MACRO {aug} {"August"}
MACRO {sep} {"September"}
MACRO {oct} {"Oktober"}
MACRO {nov} {"November"}
MACRO {dec} {"Dezember"}
MACRO {jan-feb} {"Januar--Februar"}
MACRO {mar-apr} {"Maerz--April"}
MACRO {mai-jun} {"Mai-Juni"}
MACRO {jun-jul} {"Juni--Juli"}
MACRO {jul-aug} {"Juli--August"}
MACRO {sep-oct} {"September--Oktober"}
MACRO {nov-dec} {"November--Dezember"}
MACRO {jac} {"Journal of Aicraft"}
MACRO {aiaaj} {"AIAA Journal"}
MACRO {acmcs} {"ACM Comput. Surveys"}
MACRO {acta} {"Acta Inf."}
MACRO {cacm} {"Comm. ACM"}
MACRO {ibmjrd} {"IBM J. Res. Dev."}
MACRO {ibmsj} {"IBM Syst.~J."}
MACRO {ieeese} {"IEEE Trans. Softw. Eng."}
MACRO {ieeetc} {"IEEE Trans. Comput."}
MACRO {ieeetcad}
 {"IEEE Trans. Comput.-Aided Design Integrated Circuits"}
MACRO {ipl} {"Inf. Process. Lett."}
MACRO {jacm} {"J.~Assoc. Comput. Mach."}
MACRO {jcss} {"J.~Comput. System Sci."}
MACRO {scp} {"Sci. Comput. Programming"}
MACRO {sicomp} {"SIAM J. Comput."}
MACRO {tocs} {"ACM Trans. Comput. Syst."}
MACRO {tods} {"ACM Trans. Database Syst."}
MACRO {tog} {"ACM Trans. Gr."}
MACRO {toms} {"ACM Trans. Math. Softw."}
MACRO {toois} {"ACM Trans. Office Inf. Syst."}
MACRO {toplas} {"ACM Trans. Prog. Lang. Syst."}
MACRO {tcs} {"Theoretical Comput. Sci."}

READ

FUNCTION {sortify}
{ purify$
  "l" change.case$
}

INTEGERS { len }

FUNCTION {chop.word}
{ 's :=
  'len :=
  s #1 len substring$ =
    { s len #1 + global.max$ substring$ }
    's
  if$
}

FUNCTION {sort.format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  ""
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { nameptr #1 >
    { "   " * }
    'skip$
      if$
      s nameptr "{vv{ } }{ll{ }}{  f{ }}{  jj{ }}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr numnames = t "others" = and
    { "et al" * }
    { t sortify * }
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {sort.format.title}
{ 't :=
  "A " #2
    "An " #3
      "The " #4 t chop.word
    chop.word
  chop.word
  sortify
  #1 global.max$ substring$
}

FUNCTION {author.sort}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
    { "to sort, need author or key in " cite$ * warning$
      ""
    }
    { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.sort}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need author, editor, or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { editor sort.format.names }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.organization.sort}
{ author empty$
    { organization empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need author, organization, or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { "The " #4 organization chop.word sortify }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.organization.sort}
{ editor empty$
    { organization empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need editor, organization, or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { "The " #4 organization chop.word sortify }
      if$
    }
    { editor sort.format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {presort}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.sort
    { type$ "proceedings" =
    'editor.organization.sort
    { type$ "manual" =
        'author.organization.sort
        'author.sort
      if$
    }
      if$
    }
  if$
  "    "
  *
  year field.or.null sortify
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}

ITERATE {presort}

SORT

STRINGS { longest.label }

INTEGERS { number.label longest.label.width }

FUNCTION {initialize.longest.label}
{ "" 'longest.label :=
  #1 'number.label :=
  #0 'longest.label.width :=
}

FUNCTION {longest.label.pass}
{ number.label int.to.str$ 'label :=
  number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
  label width$ longest.label.width >
    { label 'longest.label :=
      label width$ 'longest.label.width :=
    }
    'skip$
  if$
}

EXECUTE {initialize.longest.label}

ITERATE {longest.label.pass}

FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{"  longest.label  * "}" * write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {begin.bib}

EXECUTE {init.state.consts}

EXECUTE {init.last.authors}

ITERATE {call.type$}

FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {end.bib}
```

The error says that the problem is just at the end of the bst-file in the following line `ITERATE {call.type$}`.

According to the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63316399/bibtex-you-cant-pop-an-empty-literal-stack) article I tried to change from article to misc. This works and suppresses the error so far, but then all information regarding journal, volume,... is lost.

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553555/bibtex-you-cant-pop-an-empty-literal-stack-for-entry-xxxxxx) article stated that there could be a problem with day-month-year notation, but with the proposed code snippet no references could be found by BibTex at all.

I also compared all references where the error occurs with those where it doesn't, but couldn't figure out huge differences.

Thanks four your help!

Edit: Include bst-file because it was previously marked as spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is how empty `number` fields are processed by the `.bst` file. I don't recognize the .bst you are using, but the following hack seems to resolve the issue.

Insert this code into the `.bst` file after the function `format.vol.year` (after line 401 or so):

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num}
{ volume field.or.null
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {  ", Vol.~" swap$  *  }
  if$
  number field.or.null
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { ", No.~" swap$ * }
  if$ *
}
```

And in `FUNCTION {article}`, replace `format.vol.year output` by `format.vol.num output`. This fixed it on my end.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem.